# Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 10 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, chef-infra

I am getting below error while running my chef recipe. The rvm, apache passenger are installed  using community chef recipes.

```
STDERR: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 10 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Can Anyone tell me why is this error coming. I checked that the bundler gem is installed.

Comment: more details, how do you run it?

Answer (score 2):

this happens when you have only set `PATH` and not `GEM_HOME` and/or `GEM_HOME`.

Comment: I am running the rvm cookbook and the apache passenger cookbook and then my project's cookbook. I think rvm is installing bundler in ruby1.9.3@global and not in ruby1.9.3.
The code where I am getting this error is below which is part of my cookbook recipe:
  

    execute 'install olympus_app gem dependencies' do
    cwd node[:olympus_app][:dir]
    command 'bundle install --without test integration development --path vendor/cache'
    user node[:olympus_app][:apache_user]
    group node[:olympus_app][:apache_group]
    end

Comment: how do you make the installed ruby available to your receipt? are you setting `PATH`? rvm default gems are installed in @global, this is proper behavior.

Comment: I got this working. The rvm cookbook was installing the 1.8.7 version by default which was creating this problem. I am passing the default version = 1.9.3 as server attributes now.
Thanks for the help.